# How to pass parameters to \tikzstyle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, pgfkeys, optional-arguments, multipart-node

I am using multipart shapes to create two-sided nodes and want to change the background color of the left node based on a user-provided (color) parameter. Changing the default parameter at `\tikzstyle{package}[green]` also changes the background color in both outputs (Node 1+2), however I am not able to specify another color for some reason. Instead, the text color changes (Node 2).

The following example demonstrates this behavior:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, shapes.geometric, shapes.multipart}
\tikzstyle{package}[green] = [
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split parts=2,
    rectangle split part fill = { 
        #1, gray
    },
    draw=black, very thick,
    minimum height=2em,
    inner sep=1cm,
    every one node part/.style={
        text=white,
        text width=5cm
    },
    every two node part/.style={
        text=white,
        text width=\linewidth-7cm
    }
]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[package] {Node 1 \nodepart{two} Lorem Ipsum \\ dolor sit amet};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[package][red] {Node 2 \nodepart{two} Lorem Ipsum \\ dolor sit amet};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The following image shows the output. I want to fill the left side of the second node with red, instead of green.

[image]

I understand, that the red text color comes from the way, the node is drawn (i.e. the `red` does not actually specify my parameter, but instead the standard `\node` parameters). I also tried changing how to express this, for example `\node[package][fill=red]` or `\node[package, red]`, but nothing worked as expected. So my question is: How do I add parameters to a `tikzstyle` and pass arguments when drawing a node? Also, is it possible to define multiple parameters?

Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Everything about keys is detailed in section "87 Key Management" in pgf documentation. But about your code:

once you define a style with parameters, use `style=parameter_value` to change it. You construction `[package][red]` leaves `package` style with its default value and introduces the `red` as another parameter, not for filling.

If you need more than one parameter, you could use `style_name/.style 2 args` (see following code) or `style_name/.style n args={arguments number}{style definition}`. There's another option which allows a particular construction but I don't know how to use it.

By the way, I've changes old `tikzstyle` to `tikzset` (see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/1952))

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, shapes.geometric, shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{
    package/.style 2 args = {
        rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split part fill = { 
            #1, #2
        },
        draw=black, very thick,
        minimum height=2em,
        inner sep=1cm,
        every one node part/.style={
            text=white,
            text width=5cm
        },
        every two node part/.style={
            text=white,
            text width=\linewidth-7cm
        }
    },
    package/.default={green}{gray}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[package] {Node 1 \nodepart{two} Lorem Ipsum \\ dolor sit amet};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[package={red}{blue!20!black}] {Node 2 \nodepart{two} Lorem Ipsum \\ dolor sit amet};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Curiously (because I thought it was optional), `\nodepart{one}` is necessary in both examples for the text style parameters (`text` and `text width`) to take effect. Odd.

Comment: @sgmoye Yea, I forgot to include it in the MWE. I've also tried `every upper node part` in the style, but it didn't have any effect either.

Comment: @sgmoye nvm, my bad. Within the style definition you should not use the `every one node part` at all. Leave it out and set the `text` and `text width` properties directly (e.g. `style = { ..., text=white, text width=2cm, every two node part/.style = { ... }, ... }`and everything works as expected.