# How to change a \tikzstyle parameter according to a variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, parameters, variable

I'm trying to define a document where I have different levels of it contained in TikZ boxes as shown below; the idea is that each box should get a color depending on the value of the counter (which is displayed inside the circle positioned on the top of each rectangle).
[image: document structure]
Here is an extract of my code:

```latex
documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{engrec}
\usepackage{yfonts}

%\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1cm, width=19cm, top=1cm, bottom=2cm, marginpar=0pt, twoside, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1cm, width=19cm, top=1cm, bottom=2cm, marginpar=0pt, twoside]{geometry}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    positioning,
    fit,
    arrows,
    arrows.meta,
    intersections,
    decorations,
    backgrounds,
    calc,
    math,
    through,
    shapes,
    shadows,
    decorations.pathmorphing
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{Tisa OT}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros Cn}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}

\definecolor{conceptcolor}{RGB}{160,44,90}
\definecolor{subconceptcolora}{RGB}{255,102,0}
\definecolor{subconceptcolorb}{RGB}{95,95,211}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                           %
%       CONCEPT BOX         %
%                           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{conceptctr}
\renewcommand{\theconceptctr}{\Alph{conceptctr}}

\tikzstyle{conceptboxtitlesty} = 
    [
        circle,%
        draw = conceptcolor,%
        line width = 0.7mm,%
        node font = \Huge\bfseries\sffamily,%
        text = conceptcolor,%
        fill = white,%
        inner sep = 3pt%
    ]
\tikzstyle{conceptboxsty} = 
    [
        rectangle,
        rounded corners = 10pt,%
        draw = conceptcolor,
        line width = 0.7mm,%
        node font = \small
    ]
%
\NewEnviron{conceptbox}{
    \stepcounter{conceptctr}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[conceptboxsty, anchor=north west](concepttext) at (-6,0) {
            \begin{minipage}{18cm}
                \vspace{20pt}
                \BODY
            \end{minipage}
            \vspace{20pt}
        };
        \node[conceptboxtitlesty, xshift = 2cm](conecepttitle) at (concepttext.north west){\theconceptctr};

    \end{tikzpicture}
}[\newline]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                           %
%      SUBCONCEPT BOX       %
%                           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{subconceptctr}[conceptctr]
\renewcommand{\thesubconceptctr}{\arabic{subconceptctr}}
\newcommand{\subconceptcolor}[1]
    {%
       \ifthenelse{#1 = 1}%
          {subconceptcolora}%
            {%
                \ifthenelse{#1 = 2}%
                {subconceptcolorb}%
                {}%% &c.
            }%
    }

\tikzstyle{subconcepttitlesty} = 
    [
        circle,%
        draw = \currentcolor,%
        line width = 0.5mm,%
        node font = \LARGE\bfseries\sffamily,%
        text = \currentcolor,%
        fill = white,%
        inner sep = 3pt%
    ]
    \tikzstyle{subconceptboxsty} = 
    [
        rectangle,
        rounded corners = 10pt,%
        draw = \currentcolor,
        line width = 0.5mm,%
        node font = \small%
    ]
%
\newcommand{\currentcolor}{}
\NewEnviron{subconceptbox}{
    \stepcounter{subconceptctr}
    \renewcommand{\currentcolor}{\subconceptcolor{\value{subconceptctr}}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[subconceptboxsty,
            anchor=north west,
            ](subconcepttext) at (0,-1) {
            \begin{minipage}{17.5cm}
                \vspace{20pt}
                \BODY
                \vspace{10pt}
            \end{minipage}
        };%
        \node[subconcepttitlesty,
            anchor = center,
            xshift = 2cm, yshift = 0cm](subconecepttitle) at (subconcepttext.north west){\thesubconceptctr};%
    \end{tikzpicture}
}[\newline]

\begin{document}
    \begin{conceptbox}
        Il C. è \textsl{similitudo rei in mente expressa} (cioè la rappresentazione di una cosa espressa nella mente). Infatti, essa è il prodotto dell' \textsl{apprensione}, ovvero della prima operazione della mente che astrae, mediante i sensi, una rappresentazione universale di ciò che si osserva fuori di noi.\\\newline

        \begin{subconceptbox}
            Il C. ci rimanda immediatamente alla realtà e non allo stesso C. Esso significa ciò che la cosa è secondo un aspetto determinato (i.e., il concetto di "relazione" ci porta a capire cos' è una relazione; quello di "tartaruga", a capire cos' è una tartaruga). Ciò non implica una totale comprensione della natura, né che siamo capaci di definirla, ma senz' altro comporta una certa intellezione.
        \end{subconceptbox}

        \begin{subconceptbox}
            Ciò che caratterizza il C. è la sua \textit{\textbf{Universalità}}: quanto è espresso dal C. vale per tutti e per sempre, grazie al fatto che considera tutte le note essenziali che tutti gl' individui devono possedere. Grazie all' Universalità abbiamo i seguenti risultati:\par%            
        \end{subconceptbox}

    \end{conceptbox}
\end{document}
```

I had a look at this question:
[How to pass parameters to \tikzstyle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498343/how-to-pass-parameters-to-tikzstyle); and these [If-then-else inside TikZ graph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187482/if-then-else-inside-tikz-graph), [If-then-else inside TikZ graph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187482/if-then-else-inside-tikz-graph#187514).
So my understanding is that the `\ifthenelse` command is not recognized by TikZ; for this reason I've tried to pass the value of the conditional to a variable (`\currentcolor`) which, I thought, would have been initialized before calling the `tikzpicture` environment.
Still, what I get is a bunch (166) errors during compilation.
Any suggestion? Thank you for you support.

Comment: You should post a *complete* document that can be TeXed, even if with errors. It looks like you have posted (most of?) the preamble. What is needed, in addition is a `\begin{document}...\end{document}` block showing how you want to use the code. That will spark more interest.

Comment: Thank you @sgmoye, I just added as advised.

Comment: After having further and better analysed the _compiler log_, I' ve noticed the following message as first error:
```
prova3.tex:277: Undefined control sequence.
\TE@repl #1#2->\long \def \@tempc 
                                  ##1#1##2{\def \@tempa {##2}\def \@tempb {\...
l.277     \end{conceptbox}
```
So `\ifthen`,  for some to-me-unknown reason, is called within TikZ (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\tikzstyle` is deprecated. I do not have your fonts installed, but they are not relevant to the problem. `\ifthen` is not expandable, but in the case at hand you only need `\ifodd`. For more complex situations you can use pgf to define the color.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1cm, width=19cm, top=1cm, bottom=2cm, marginpar=0pt, twoside]{geometry}

\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    positioning,
    fit,
    arrows,
    arrows.meta,
    intersections,
    decorations,
    backgrounds,
    calc,
    math,
    through,
    shapes,
    shadows,
    decorations.pathmorphing
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{conceptcolor}{RGB}{160,44,90}
\definecolor{subconceptcolora}{RGB}{255,102,0}
\definecolor{subconceptcolorb}{RGB}{95,95,211}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                           %
%       CONCEPT BOX         %
%                           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{conceptctr}
\renewcommand{\theconceptctr}{\Alph{conceptctr}}

\tikzset{conceptboxtitlesty/.style={
        circle,%
        draw = conceptcolor,%
        line width = 0.7mm,%
        node font = \Huge\bfseries\sffamily,%
        text = conceptcolor,%
        fill = white,%
        inner sep = 3pt%
    },
conceptboxsty/.style={
        rectangle,
        rounded corners = 10pt,%
        draw = conceptcolor,
        line width = 0.7mm,%
        node font = \small
    }}
%
\NewEnviron{conceptbox}{
    \stepcounter{conceptctr}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[conceptboxsty, anchor=north west](concepttext) at (-6,0) {
            \begin{minipage}{18cm}
                \vspace{20pt}
                \BODY
            \end{minipage}
            \vspace{20pt}
        };
        \node[conceptboxtitlesty, xshift = 2cm](conecepttitle) at (concepttext.north west){\theconceptctr};

    \end{tikzpicture}
}[\newline]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                           %
%      SUBCONCEPT BOX       %
%                           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{subconceptctr}[conceptctr]
\renewcommand{\thesubconceptctr}{\arabic{subconceptctr}}

\tikzset{subconcepttitlesty/.style={
        circle,%
        draw = \currentcolor,%
        line width = 0.5mm,%
        node font = \LARGE\bfseries\sffamily,%
        text = \currentcolor,%
        fill = white,%
        inner sep = 3pt%
    },
subconceptboxsty/.style={
        rectangle,
        rounded corners = 10pt,%
        draw = \currentcolor,
        line width = 0.5mm,%
        node font = \small%
    }}
%
\newcommand{\currentcolor}{}

\NewEnviron{subconceptbox}{
    \stepcounter{subconceptctr}
    \ifodd\value{subconceptctr}
    \renewcommand{\currentcolor}{subconceptcolora}
    \else
    \renewcommand{\currentcolor}{subconceptcolorb}
    \fi
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[subconceptboxsty,
            anchor=north west,
            ](subconcepttext) at (0,-1) {
            \begin{minipage}{17.5cm}
                \vspace{20pt}
                \BODY
                \vspace{10pt}
            \end{minipage}
        };%
        \node[subconcepttitlesty,
            anchor = center,
            xshift = 2cm, yshift = 0cm](subconecepttitle) at (subconcepttext.north west){\thesubconceptctr};%
    \end{tikzpicture}
}[\newline]

\begin{document}
    \begin{conceptbox}
        Il C. \`e \textsl{similitudo rei in mente expressa} (cio\`e la
        rappresentazione di una cosa espressa nella mente). Infatti,
        essa \`e il prodotto dell' \textsl{apprensione}, ovvero della
        prima operazione della mente che astrae, mediante i sensi, una
        rappresentazione universale di ci\`o che si osserva fuori di noi.\\\newline

        \begin{subconceptbox}
            Il C. ci rimanda immediatamente alla realt\`a e non allo stesso C.
Esso significa ci\`o che la cosa e secondo un aspetto determinato (i.e., il
concetto di "relazione" ci porta a capire cos' \`e una relazione; quello di
"tartaruga", a capire cos' \`e una tartaruga). Ci\`o non implica una totale
comprensione della natura, n\'e che siamo capaci di definirla, ma senz' altro
comporta una certa intellezione.
        \end{subconceptbox}

        \begin{subconceptbox}
            Cio che caratterizza il C. \`e la sua
\textit{\textbf{Universalit\'a}}: quanto \`e espresso dal C. vale per tutti e
per sempre, grazie al fatto che considera tutte le note essenziali che tutti gl'
individui devono possedere. Grazie all' Universalita abbiamo i seguenti
risultati:\par%            
        \end{subconceptbox}

\end{conceptbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that using `tcolorbox` will be a much better way to create these frames. This answer is only to remove the error from the code, not to provide a `tcolorbox` code, which I however think will make more sense.

Comment: Thank you for your illuminating and extremely helpful reply. Really appreciated!

Comment: AndI discovered a new package! :-))